# Selenium 2: moveByOffset() and consecutive release() - strange positioning

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2 with FirefoxDriver. The task is to move an element for a few pixels. I code the task this way:

```
val action = (new Actions(driver)).clickAndHold(el).moveByOffset(3,1).release().perform()
```

mouseDown(), mouseMove() and mouseUp() events are logged. So I receive the following output:

```
mouseDown at 267 133
mouseMove at 270 134
mouseMove at 267 133
mouseUp at 267 133
```

It looks like that Selenium calls mouseDown on the item, then moves it to the specified position, then **moves it back** and then calls mouseUp. That's pretty strange.

It turns out that the reason is in release() call, since when I call this:

```
val action = (new Actions(driver)).clickAndHold(el).moveByOffset(3,1).perform()
```

I get this:

```
mouseDown at 267 133
mouseMove at 270 134
```

How to make Selenium to call mouseUp at the right position?

Comment: Got the same behavior using ChromeDriver

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bug... A possible workaround would be:

val action = (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDropToOffset(el, el.Location.X + 3, el.Location.Y + 1).perform()