# Timing of mouse movement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseevent

I'd like to record some mouse interaction with a web page, or more specifically, with a canvas element on that web page. So interacting with various web elements will be of little use, and instead interacting with the canvas with fine position control is essential.

For a while I was looking at the [`Mouse`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Mouse.html) interface. I was somewhat surprised that I could provide offset for movement, but not for `mouseDown` and `mouseUp`. It also took me a while to figure out that I can probably turn a [`WebElement`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) into [`Coordinates`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/interactions/internal/Coordinates.html) by casting it to the [`Locatable`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/internal/Locatable.html) interface first.

But `Locatable` and `Coordinates` are in a package called `internal`. Eventually (with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9735719/1468366)) I learned about [`Actions`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html). Its documentation states:

> The user-facing API for emulating complex user gestures. Use this class rather than using the Keyboard or Mouse directly.

So it seems that I should be using this. Expressing my movement in that context seems easy enough. But what has me worried is timing. I'd like to move objects approximately at the same speed I used when recording. I'm not aiming to exactly reproduce timing, but some mouse actions will trigger computations in a timer step, so the interaction between mouse events and timer should be simulated in a natural fashion.

I see no `wait` or `sleep` method in `Actions`. What I do see is a `pause` method, but that has been deprecated. The deprecation message reads:

> 'Pause' is considered to be a bad design practice.

The [commit](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=a7d53122fd86ea268078fbd125bcaa45ab124f57) adding that deprecation has no more detail either.

- Why is `pause` considered bad design?
- Can I expect drivers to support this command despite the deprecation?
- Do I have to fear that this command will vanish soon?
- How else should I implement timing of mouse movement?

There appears to be plenty of places where some form of waiting can be realized. [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and [`WebDriver.Timeouts`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html) seem the most likely candidates. But would it really be preferable to perform `Actions` consisting of a single mouse move, and interleave them with waits? Particularly if I might be remote controlling some machine over a slow link? Interleaving `pause` statements in a long `Actions` sequence seemed so much more reasonable to me.

*Edit 1:* Looking at [the sources](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/PauseAction.java) I see that `Actions.pause` is simply implemented using `Thread.sleep`. So the delay is only local, and network latency over a bad link might severely distort timing. I also found two bug reports regarding `Actions.pause`, [one](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7424) requesting that it not be deprecated and [another](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7646) reuqesting an alternative. The latter comes with a proof-of-concept implementation building on `WebDriverWait`. But looking at that, it bases its timing on `Clock` and the only implementation of that interface is `SystemClock` so it appears that again all timing is controlled client-side. What we'd need would be some on-the-wire command for a server-side delay, I think.